# MDX navigation in SET not working (Lag, Lead, PrevMember, ...)

Tags: mdx

I've got the following problem with my MDX statement. The previous element in the created set "[S_PrevDate]" is not accessible due to the where clause. The calculated member "x" returns an empty set. Without where-clause it is working fine.

@Month = "[Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].&[201709]"

```
WITH
SET [S_PrevDate] AS
    StrToMember(@Month, CONSTRAINED).PrevMember

MEMBER x AS
    SetToStr([S_PrevDate])

SELECT x ON 0 FROM [cube]

WHERE StrToMember(@Month, CONSTRAINED)
```

In fact, selecting another month isn't working either. "x" remains empty:

```
WITH
SET [S_PrevDate] AS
    [Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].&[201708]    -- August

MEMBER x AS
    SetToStr([S_PrevDate])

SELECT x ON 0 FROM [cube]

WHERE [Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].&[201709]    -- September
```

What am I missing or how can I work around this issue? The set will be used in quite some calculations and needs to be created in the query scope.

Answer (score 0):

Do really need a set? Try it:

```
WITH    
MEMBER x AS
    SetToStr([Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].&[201708] )

SELECT x ON 0 FROM [cube]

WHERE [Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].&[201709]    -- September
```

Comment: I'm in need of a set because I want to use the set in multiple calculated members using an aggregate function e.g. Sum([S_PrevDate], [Measures].[measure 1])

Comment: Replace [S_PrevDate] with your real set.

Comment: I was hoping I could use some caching benefits if the set is only evaluated once instead of 10+ times each. The real set I use is a little bit bigger, but not that much of a problem.

Comment: In that case you have to provide the full code. We can't help you if we don't understand your aim.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the WHERE clause in your script? `WHERE` happens very early in execution order of an mdx script - and creates the scope.

You have:

```
WITH
  SET [S_PrevDate] AS
    StrToMember(@Month, CONSTRAINED).PrevMember
MEMBER x AS SetToStr([S_PrevDate])
SELECT x ON 0 
FROM [cube]
WHERE StrToMember(@Month, CONSTRAINED);
```

I don't understand why you cannot just drop the `WHERE` clause?

```
WITH
  SET [S_PrevDate] AS
    StrToMember(@Month, CONSTRAINED).PrevMember
MEMBER x AS SetToStr([S_PrevDate])
SELECT x ON 0 
FROM [cube];
```

This might also be an alternative:

```
WITH
SET [MTH] AS 
    StrToSet("{" + @Month + "}", CONSTRAINED)
SET [S_PrevDate] AS
    [MTH].ITEM(0).PrevMember
MEMBER x AS
    SetToStr([S_PrevDate])
SELECT x ON 0 
FROM [cube];
```

Comment: The code was just meant as a demo of showing that you can't create sets with members, which are excluded in either subcube or where clause. In my real code I have a time range in the where clause and want a set of another time range for comparison. The set will be used quite often, so I hoped for little caching benefits and tidy code.

Comment: WHERE is a filter - you say "you can't create sets with members, which are excluded in either subcube or where clause" - this is obvious. In most declarative languages or logic if you filter something out then it is not available. If you want it to be available then don't filter it out.